# Speech Recognition UnknownValueError

Tags: python

I have tried it on python shell 3.5.8

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser as wb

chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe 
%s'


# obtain audio from the microphone  
r = sr.Recognizer()  
with sr.Microphone() as source:  
   print("Please wait. Calibrating microphone...")  
   # listen for 5 seconds and create the ambient noise energy level  
   r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=5)  
   print("Say something!")  
   audio = r.listen(source)  

# recognize speech 
try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("I thinks you said '" + r.recognize_google(audio) + "'")

    f_text='https://www.google.co.in/search?q=' + text
    wb.get(chrome_path).open(f_text)
#except sr.UnknownValueError:  
#  print("I could not understand audio")  
except sr.RequestError as e:  
   print("error; {0}".format(e))

except Exception as e:
   print (e)
```

```
File "C:\Users\manoj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site- 
packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or 
len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

Comment: Check the documentation. The problem is with recognize_google usage. I'd say, first try to run it only once, not twice. :P

Comment: ok thank you, will try to move recognize_google(audio) out of the try block and will try print the audio once, if it works will let you know on this, And if possible can you provide me the link for documentation to check details.

Comment: What I meant is that you have `text = r.recognize_google(audio)` and then another recognize in the print statement. You haven't included the stacktrace, so this is only a guess

Comment: i did removed r.recognize_google(audio) from the print statement with the variable name(text), but getting the same error.

Comment: I think I got the issue if I ran the  python -m speech_recognition in cmd and if I speak it is not transcribing my speech, so this might be the issue, please do find this for your reference and kindly help me on the same to fix the issue PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python -m speech_recognition
A moment of silence, please...
Set minimum energy threshold to 171.88727223022704
Say something!

Comment: Hi,issue got resolved after using 3.6 version. Thanks for help

Comment: I also did face the same issue while running on google Colab but it had worked fine when I tried running on my local system. Still don't know why is it so!!

Answer (score 6):

try this out

```
try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-IN', show_all = True )
    print("I thinks you said '" + r.recognize_google(audio) + "'")

    f_text='https://www.google.co.in/search?q=' + text
    wb.get(chrome_path).open(f_text)
```

I think this is happen because of noise interrupts algorithm. due to noise it gives UnknownValueError

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import walk

r = sr.Recognizer()
#optional
#r.energy_threshold = 300

def startConvertion(path = 'file.wav', lang = 'en-IN'): 
    with sr.AudioFile(path) as source:
        #print('Fetching File')
        audio_file = r.record(source)
        print(r.recognize_google(audio_file, language=lang))
startConvertion()
```